# Target one specific workbook among multiple workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

So I have this code to update links within my excel workbook

```
Dim alertTime As Date

Public Sub Refresh()
'refresh
ActiveWorkbook.UpdateLink (ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources)
'Workbooks("Requests").UpdateLink (Workbooks("Requests").LinkSources)
alertTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:05") 'hh:mm:ss
    Application.OnTime alertTime, "Refresh"
Debug.Print Now() & " - Links Updated"

'MsgBox "5 Seconds have passed, refreshing", vbInformation, "Debug"

End Sub
Sub StopRefresh()
    Application.OnTime alertTime, "Refresh", , False
End Sub
```

The code works, but as soon as I open up another workbook and the refresh triggers and it errors out.  I want to be able to target that specific workbook for the refresh command.

Any help is welcomed.

Comment: Doesn't the commented out line do that? Comment out the activeworkbooks one and uncomment the other one.

Comment: It throws a Runtime Error '9': Subscript out of range. :/

Answer (score 0):

You might need to put the sheet too like:

```
workbooks("Requests").Sheets("Sheetname").UpdateLink(Workbooks("Requests").Sheets("Sheetname").LinkSources)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your statement `ActiveWorkbook.UpdateLink (ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources)` updates the link in the "Active" Workbook.  That's the workbook that you are currently working on.  When you open a new workbook, the new workbook becomes the active workbook.

Instead of `ActiveWorkbook.UpdateLink (ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources)` try this:

```
Workbooks("nameOfWorkbook").UpdateLink (Workbooks("nameOfWorkbook").LinkSources)
```

Where nameOfWorkbook is the filename of the workbook *(i.e., filename, extension and path if necessary)* for which you want to update links.  For example,

```
Workbooks("Requests.xlsb").UpdateLink (Workbooks("Requests.xlsb").LinkSources)
```

If the active directory is different than the directory in which Requests.xlsb is saved, then you must include the full path, like this:

```
Workbooks("C:\Users\yourID\Documents\Requests.xlsb").UpdateLink _
   (Workbooks("C:\Users\yourID\Documents\Requests.xlsb").LinkSources)
```

or more concisely:

```
With Workbooks("C:\Users\yourID\Documents\Requests.xlsb")
    .UpdateLink .LinkSources
End with
```

Comment: Tried that one, thats what the comment following that line is :)

Comment: nameOfworkbook must be the actual filename *including extension*.   Try \n `Workbooks("Requests.xlsb").UpdateLink (Workbooks("Requests.xlsb").LinkSources)`.  If the active directory is different than the directory in which Requests.xlsb is saved, then you must use `'Workbooks("C:\Users\yourID\Documents\Requests.xlsb").UpdateLink (Workbooks("C:\Users\yourID\Documents\Requests.xlsb").LinkSources)`.

Comment: Did the comment about using the file extension help?

Comment: Yes, have tried both ways.  

A simple solution that I've implemented for the short-term whcih suppresses the error is to target "'Requests.xlsm'!Refresh" which seems to work.